# Geoserver null return after a wfs transaction

Tags: gis, layer, geoserver

I was wondering if there is a way to change which column of a table is returned by geoserver after a insert transaction. I have a layer street_segment that has as a primary key the column FeatId (autoincrement). In the geoserver demo requests whenever i perform a insert transaction, geoserver responds with  like in the screenshot. The record however is created in the postgres database with only the primary key FeatId inserted and all other fields are null (eventhough they have default values). Is there any way to configure the geoserver WFS service to return FeatId instead of fid when a transaction is executed ? The fid column is not present in the database. I have tried to remove and re-add the layer and republish it but still the same result.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Your primary key should be used as the `fid` so your layer may be incorrectly set up